# Open image of the singer by LastFM and function (artist.getinfo)

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml, last.fm

Good, I have this code of LastFM API

```html
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=ARIANA GRANDE&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
$largeImage = $xml->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" />';     
?>
```

it appears used the image of Ariana Grande a php page.

Now the link of my XML file is :http://radiojoven.6te.net/playlist.xml

Well, what I am trying to do is change "ARIANA GRANDE" (the artist's name) in the link of the "simplexml_load_file" (in the php code) with the info that my XML file provides. I tried to make a code like this but to no avail.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://radiojoven.6te.net/playlist.xml');
$artist = urlencode($xml->Event->Song->Artist['name'];); 
$url = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist='.$artist.'&api_key=50ac27433c63f7298064f434f4ef6d15);
$xml2 = @simplexml_load_file($url);
$largeImage = $xml2->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" />';     
?>
```

Can you please help me doing this?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few errors in your code.

Remove the semicolon after `['name'];` in this line:

```
$artist = urlencode($xml->Event->Song->Artist['name'];);
```

Missing double quotes after `api_key=50ac27433c63f7298064f434f4ef6d15` and I think `'.$artist.'` should be `$artist` in this line:

```
$url = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist='.$artist.'&api_key=50ac27433c63f7298064f434f4ef6d15);
```

I don't think that you need this line:

```
$xml2 = @simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Then in this line change `$xml2` to `$url`:

```
$largeImage = $xml2->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
```

So your code would become like this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://radiojoven.6te.net/playlist.xml');
$artist = urlencode($xml->Event->Song->Artist['name']);
$url = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=$artist&api_key=50ac27433c63f7298064f434f4ef6d15");
$largeImage = $url->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" />';     
?>
```

Comment: I think OP would profit from learning basic troubleshooting skills

Comment: Thank you very much for your help The fourth bird , good 2016

Comment: @AndréSantos You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you can always consider marking the answer as accepted. Cheers and a good 2016!